# How can I get my input value from input field in a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value from an input field and display it using a `div` tag, but it's not displaying anything. Where am I wrong?

```
var num = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
var numbersList = document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;
```

```
<input type="text" id="inputNum">
<div id="numbers">
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit you question accordingly.

Comment: You need to use onchange event to display every key stoke into the div

Comment: your code is invalid remove the assignment part and just aaply the text, you dont need to store in numberslist, and events is whole another story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="inputNum">

<div id = "numbers">

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var num = document.getElementById("inputNum");
var numbersList = document.getElementById('numbers');

num.onkeyup= function(e){
 numbersList.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}
```

`keyup` will detect every key that is being typed and it will display to the `div`

Comment: Thankyou so much...as simple as that...i really wanted this...it worked..

Comment: It would be great if you could mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the tick symbol :)

Comment: I am new to stack-overflow I tried to upvote you but my vote is not added due to low reputation score.

Comment: But is it possible for you to Mark the answer as Accepted by clicking on the tick icon?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `onkeyup` event. This will give you ever character from text box. After getting the value you can easily set it using `innerHTML`. Consider the following snippet:

```html
<script>
function setValue(){
   var num = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
   document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;
}
</script>
<input type = "text" id ="inputNum" onkeyup="setValue()">
<div id = "numbers">
```

Answer (score 0):

So a few things is happening below.

First, we ensure that the whole page is loaded. Why? If your script is loaded at the beginning, it may have troubles accessing the DOMs (`input`, `textarea`, `div`, etc). Of course, if you load the Javascript at the botton of your page, you can skip such issue.

However, I decided to implement the `(function() {...});` self-execute function. This will ensure your Javascript runs after the page its loaded.

Then, I added an event listener to the DOM object of `inputNum`. This listener will keep an eye to `keyup` events of your keyword. Each time a key goes up, after being pressed, it will run the code inside the function.

```js
// This function will execute when the whole page is loaded
// This means that all the DOMs (such as your input and div) will be available
(function() {
  var inputNum = document.getElementById("inputNum");
  inputNum.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
     var num = inputNum.value;
     document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;
  });  
})();
```

```html
<input type = "text" id ="inputNum">
<div id = "numbers"></div>
```

Note: I could have use the attribute `keyup=''` in the input field; however, I decided to give you an answer that provides 100% control. In this way, you can decide which type of event is more appropriate to the project you are working with.

Comment: Thanks. Its working too...and i got my doubt clear...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In `var numbersList = document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;` just omit `var numbersList =`. Code `document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;` will set innerHTML of Element with Id = "numbers" and will not return anything.
Your code will be:

```
var num = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;
```

or just

```
document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems, and your needs aren't totally clear, but hopefully this will help. Here are the things I fixed:

This line

```
var numbersList = document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;
```

contains an error because it has two equals signs. I replaced it with two lines, first identifying the element and saving it to the variable `numbersList`, then setting the `innerHTML` property of `numbersList` to the `num` discovered above.

Secondly, the javascript you've written will presumably run once, when the page is loaded. At that time the `input` contains no text, so there's nothing to copy to the `div`. Depending on what you're trying to do, there are a few ways to handle this, but as one example, I've put the code you wrote (with the above fix) into a function, then added a button and assigned the function to run when the button is clicked.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```js
function copyVal() {
  var num = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
  var numbersList = document.getElementById('numbers')
  numbersList.innerHTML = num;
}

document.getElementById('copy').onclick = copyVal;
```

```html
<input type = "text" id ="inputNum">
<div id = "numbers"></div>
<button id="copy">copy text</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou for explaining and clearing the doubt. I skipped the error of  "two assignment operator"...thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = document.getElementById("inputNum");
var numbersList = document.getElementById('numbers');

num.addEventListener('change', function(){
  numbersList.textContent = this.value;
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend some time and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and then you can edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var num = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = num;
```